# Dot products in special relativity

Tags: special-relativity, metric-tensor, vectors, inertial-frames

I am trying to calculate dot products in special relativity. For example consider a particle moving at speed $v$ relative to a rest frame. $P$ and $U$ are 4-momentum and 4-velocity respectively.

I get $$ P \cdot U = (E/c, \mathbf{p})^T \cdot (\gamma c, \gamma \mathbf{u})^T = Ec/c + m\gamma \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} = m\gamma c^2 + m\gamma v^2 = m\gamma (c^2 + v^2) .$$

Similarly, I get $$ U \cdot U = (\gamma c, \gamma \mathbf{u})^T \cdot (\gamma c, \gamma \mathbf{u})^T = \gamma c^2 + \gamma \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{u} = \gamma(c^2 + v^2).$$

Finally, I get $$ P \cdot P = (E/c, \mathbf{p})^T \cdot (E/c, \mathbf{p})^T = E^2/c^2 + \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{p}.$$

Some of these calculations appear to contradict results I've read elsewhere. Are these results correct and if they are not then what is my misconception while making these calculations?

Comment: What do you mean by "dot product" here? You seem to be using the [*Euclidean*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_space) inner product, but special relativity uses the [*Minkowski*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space) inner product. Why are you trying to compute "dot products" in SR if you don't even know how they are defined in the first place?

Comment: Well, I want to use the inner product to calculate those quantities correctly @ACuriousMind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @ACuriousMind noted, you need the *Minkwoski* inner product, which is non-Euclidean. So the $+$ should be a $-$. You've also miscounted $\gamma$ factors: it should be $U\cdot U=\gamma^2(c^2-v^2)=c^2$. (This is the $+---$ convention; in the $-+++$ convention, $U\cdot U=-c^2$.)